# useState with instance of class. How to effectively update it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I want to save data of 2D Polygons in a useState. I have a Storage class in which I store objects like polygons, but also other objects.
I update the state in rapid time if something is being moved. All the Vectors of the moved Polygon need to be updated.
But I dont want to copy all instances of classes in Storage so that React triggers a rerender because that results in performance issues. So I decided to put the Storage instance in an array and with every state change I put the Storage in a new Array and I just copy those Polygons that need to be updated.

The problem is that react sometimes does things twice. I know there is probably a problem with not copying the whole Storage Class but I dont exactly get Why or if its even possible what I am trying to do. If its not possible are there any other possible solutions?

I made a simplified [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-mclean-td3ch7?file=/src/App.tsx) to display the problem.

Iam thankful for every answer that could help me understand this.

Comment: I would use a ref instead https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-austin-g8lhds?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @Rotem Also thanks to you. That link helped me understand many thing better now.